# Parsing XML with Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Very straightforward piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">          
            function loadXMLDoc(dname)
            {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
                xhttp.send();
                return xhttp.responseXML;
            }


            xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("feedback.xml");

            x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("quote");
            for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            { 
                document.write(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                document.write("<br>");
            }
        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm loading the XML file "feedback.xml" which looks like this:

```
<feedback>
   <quote id="1">"This is a quote."</quote>
   <quote id="2">"This is another quote."</quote>
</feedback>
```

I got the code from http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_list_loop but nothing is really happening. When I just try to `alert(x)` to check what's inside I get an "[object HTMLCollection]". However, when I want to check `alert(x[0])` I get "undefined". Any ideas why this isn't working? It seems straightforward enough, the XML file is in the same folder as this html file and Firebug doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: Have you checked, that the XML is really returned?

Comment: alert(xmlDoc) is giving me an [object XMLDocument]

Comment: may be your `feedback.xml` is not at right location.

Comment: It's in the same folder, right next to this html file.

Comment: Try adding <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> to your xml.

Comment: @Aston What sorcery is this? Thanks Aston! You can put this as an answer if you like so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` to the top of the xml was my original suggestion. However, I have checked on my Firefox in Ubuntu and your code is just working. I tried to change the encoding maybe that is the problem, but it was not.

Originally I thought that the XML document without the heading is not recognized by Javascript as the same object. But again, on my Ubuntu in Firefox there was no difference, the document is XMLDocument and the list is HTMLCollection ...

So really I am confused what is/was the problem.